# How can I update a linearmodels PanelResults object with custom bootstrap estimates?

Tags: python, oop, linearmodels

I built my own class to implement an estimation procedure (call it `EstimationProcedure`). To run the procedure, the user calls method `fit`. First, this fits a Pooled OLS model using the [`fit`](https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/panel/panel/linearmodels.panel.model.PooledOLS.fit.html#linearmodels.panel.model.PooledOLS.fit) method of the [`PooledOLS`](https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/panel/panel/linearmodels.panel.model.PooledOLS.html) class from the [`linearmodels`](https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/) package. This returns a [`PanelResults`](https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/panel/panel/linearmodels.panel.results.PanelEffectsResults.html#linearmodels.panel.results.PanelEffectsResults) object which I store in variable `model`. Second, my `fit` method estimates, e.g., standard errors, t-statistics, p-values, etc. (using a custom bootstrapping method I wrote) whose results are stored in local variables, e.g., `std_errors`, `tstats`, `pvalues`, etc. My method shall now return a `PanelResults` object that combines information from the initial estimation and my own estimates (because I want to use `linearmodel`'s capabilities to compare multiple regressions and produce latex output).

To this end, I need to create a new `PanelResults` object. However, the necessary information is not accessible through attributes of `model`.

Conceptually, what would I need to do to implement this? Or is there a smarter way to achieve this? I suppose that this is rather a question on OOP which I have no experience with.

The following code illustrates the structure of my class:

```py
from linearmodels.panel import PooledOLS
from linearmodels.panel.results import PanelResults

class EstimationProcedure:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
    
    def fit(self):
        # estimate Pooled OLS
        model = PooledOLS(self.data)

        # construct my own results using a bootstrap procedure
        # this requires the result from an initial PooledOLS estimation
        std_errors, tstats, pvalues = self.bootstrap(self.data)
            
        # to create and return a new PanelResults object, I need 
        # to pass a number of results, say `res`, from the initial
        # pooled OLS estimation along with my own results to the
        # constructor. However, `PooledOLS` prepares 
        # estimation results required by `PanelResults`'s
        # constructor internally without making them accessible
        # through attributes. Hence, I cannot "recreate" it.
        res = dict()
        return PanelResults(res)

# data is stored in some dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()

# usage of my estimation procedure
model = EstimationProcedure(df)
model.fit()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a subclass of `PanelResults` named `CustomPanelResults` (line 1) and override its constructor to take in your custom results (line 2). Then call the constructor of the parent class with the results from the `PooledOLS` estimation (line 3) along with your custom results (line 4) to create a new `PanelResults` object that includes both sets of results.

```
class CustomPanelResults(PanelResults):              # line 1
    def __init__(self, model, custom_results):       # line 2
        super().__init__(model)                      # line 3
        self.custom_results = custom_results         # line 4
```

Then modify the `fit` method of your `EstimationProcedure` class to create an instance of this subclass and pass in the necessary arguments to its constructor:

```
def fit(self):
    model = PooledOLS(self.data)
    std_errors, tstats, pvalues = self.bootstrap(self.data)
    res = {'std_errors': std_errors, 'tstats': tstats, 'pvalues': pvalues}
    return CustomPanelResults(model, res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very clean solution, but sometimes its impossible to do otherwise.

1. Create child class of PooledOLS

```
class CustomPooledOLS(PooledOLS):
```

2. Find where is method (or methods) that computes what you need. I assume PooledOLS calculates something you need and disregards it afterwards.
3. Overwrite method(s) that compute(s) things you need and change it so it saves what you need in some parameter

```
def nameOfTheFunction(all, of, the, function, arguments):
    # - here copy all of the original function code
    # - modify it so that it saves in the object what is needed, e.g.
    this.tstats_cache = temp_tstats 
    # later you can use those in EsimationProcedure to feed to PanelResults
```

I had difficulty understanding all your needs, but hopefully this helps you

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I don't see how that will expose all results computed within PooledOLS to construct the PanelResults object.